# ¿Como eliminar un token en c# para cerrar la sesión de un Web Api?

Tags: c#, tokens

```
   public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var parameters = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
        csUsuarios objUsuarios = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<csUsuarios>(parameters.Get("strDatos"));
        if (objUsuarios == null || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objUsuarios.strNombreUsuario) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(objUsuarios.strContraseñaUsuario)
                  || string.IsNullOrEmpty(objUsuarios.intTurnoUsuario.ToString())) )
            context.SetError("strMensajeAutentificacion", "Parametros con valores incorrectos.");
        else
        {
            objUsuarios = new csModUsuarios().mtdAutentificacionUsuario(objUsuarios.strNombreUsuario, objUsuarios.strContraseñaUsuario, objUsuarios.intTurnoUsuario, objUsuarios.strNombrePC);
            string strDatosHotelJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objUsuarios);

            var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "csUsuarios", strDatosHotelJson } });

            if (objUsuarios.strMensajeAutentificacion.Contains("Acceso denegado"))
            {
                context.SetError("strMensajeAutentificacion", "El nombre de usuario o la contraseña no son correctos.");
                return;
            }
            if (objUsuarios.strMensajeAutentificacion == string.Empty || objUsuarios.strMensajeAutentificacion.Contains("cierre del dia"))
            {
                ///generacion del token
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserName", context.UserName));

                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
                context.Validated(ticket);
                context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(identity);
                ///fin de generacion del token
            }
            else
                context.SetError("strMensajeAutentificacion", objUsuarios.strMensajeAutentificacion);
        }
    }
```

Si me genera el token y cuando lo autentifico desde un cliente me proporciona el acceso, pero quisiera saber si puedo eliminarlo o expirarlo para cerrar la sesión desde una petición a un controlador, por su atención gracias!!

Comment: Puedes crear un metodo, y ese metodo que solo sea ejecutado por un rol administrador, donde tu cierres cualquier sesion de usuario. Debes agregar mas informacion de que quieres hacer y como hacerlo, es decir establecer toda la secuencia de que tu cierras la sesion y porque. Y que pasa del lado del usuario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que usas la clase `OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext` asumo que atenticas a los usuarios con [Owin Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthgrantresourceownercredentialscontext(v=vs.113).aspx) y la forma para salir de manera segura y destruir la identidad generada sería con:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    IOwinContext ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    IAuthenticationManager authManager = ctx.Authentication;
    authManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
}
```